# How to avoid/remove the unwanted characters insertions while importing .csv files into sqlite DB Browser?

Tags: sqlite, csv

I have a file in CSV format which I want to import into SQLite DB Browser.

This is how it looks when opened in excel.

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDi4u.png)

When I import the file into the SQLite database, a diamond with a question mark gets inserted, which is creating problems while executing queries.

This is how it looks when imported into SQLite DB Browser.

[SQLite DB browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVQ8h.png)

I have two questions -

- Why does it get inserted ?
- How can this be avoided/removed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while, but I solved my problem by using "***trim()***".

`UPDATE table_name SET column)name = trim(column_name, "�");`

Got help from [this](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-trim/).

Still, I couldn't find any suitable answer to the first part of my question.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.